# Multiline input with cc.EditBox ccui.TextField in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-js

How to make multiline input in Cocos2d-JS?

I try to use `cc.EditBox()` and `ccui.TextField()`, but it works only in oneline mode.

Run on platforms: iOS, Android

Thanks!

Duplicated here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues/1761

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure about cocos-JS, but in cocos2d-x it can't be done easily, since non of the standard components not provide multiline editing feature.

In cocos2d-x we can show native android / ios view with native components but its not very pleasant workaround.